# POS Terminal Swipe card Output is not readable

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, finance, payment-processing, iso8583

I have a POS terminal card reader. When I swipe my bank card then I get a stream of data.

When I read [wiki about Magnetic strip card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card) , I found that every card should return value which start with "%B ...."  or something like that ...

But my problem is I don't know what I get from swipe card. 
 
Moreover, I don't think that it is standard format which every program can read and sent to Bank Switch Server.

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to be careful with what information is posted here on SO...

Comment: What do you mean I don't know what I'm getting. Are you receiving anything at all? Or it's all encrypted? Also it would be helpful if you post exactly what kind of hardware are you using and what kind of SDK.